# Android app activity to control NXT motor even when i'm in another activity. possible?

Tags: android, android-activity, nxt, lego-mindstorms

I'm controlling NXT motor through android app "MindstormsGamepad".
and I'm trying to get the motor keep moving even when I go back or change activity in the app.

the code used is:

```
if (data.getStringExtra(Test.RESULT.equals("FORWARD")) {
                contentTxt.setText("Action: Going Forward");
                Toast.makeText(this,"Result = FORWARD",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                code = 1;
            } else if (data.getStringExtra(Test.RESULT.equals("BACK")) {
                contentTxt.setText("Action: Going Back");
                Toast.makeText(this,"Result = BACK",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                code = 2;
}
direction = code; 
sendMove_seekbar(direction);
```

with this code, it stops as soon as I press any button or change from activity to another within the app.

how to solve this ? any help is appreciated. thanks

Comment: Use service. That runs in background

Answer (score 0):

On Android, in order for a program to run in the background, you need to implement it as a [Service](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html). You need to move the code that you want to keep running to a Service and the change the Activity to interact with the Service instead.

Comment: in this activity class file
`public class xxxactivity extends CommonActivity implements
  OnClickListener {`
and
`sendMove_seekbar(direction);`
is in another class file which use
`public class CommonActivity extends Activity {`

how can I implement it as a service ?